# Find the inverses of 2,3,...,16 modulo 17.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I need to find the inverses of 2,3,...,16 modulo 17 and use to solve 
(a) 5x ≡ 9 (mod 17);
(b) 11x ≡ 3 (mod 17).

I found the inverse of 5 modulo 17, to be 7 modulo 17 and know to solve by multiplying both sides of 5x ≡ 9 (mod 17) by 7, not sure how to pass this point.

Comment: As for finding the inverses, you could do it via trial and error, or you could use the euclidean algorithm to find them, but this would take a good bit of tedious work.  As for using this information, if you have $5x\equiv 9\pmod{17}$ then $5x\cdot 7 \equiv 9\cdot 7\pmod{17}$ but since $5\cdot 7\equiv 1\pmod{17}$ this implies that $x\equiv 9\cdot 7\pmod{17}$.  So, calculate what $9\cdot 7\pmod{17}$ is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To calculate them all in a batch, it's probably better to use factorisation:

$0 \times 17 + 1$ is just $1$ so it will yield nothing.

$1 \times 17 + 1 = 18$, which is $2 \times 9 = 3 \times 6$. Therefore $2^{-1} = 9$ and $3^{-1} = 6$.

$2 \times 17 + 1 = 35$, which is $5 \times 7$. Therefore $5^{-1} = 7$.

And so on.

Once you have $5^{-1} = 7$, then $5x \equiv 9 \pmod{17}$ implies $7 \times 5x \equiv 7 \times 9$, so $x \equiv 63 \equiv 12$.

Comment: Steven +1 beat me to it! Here is the  list as I'd worked it out $(16,16)(15,8)(4,13)(2,9 )(1,1)(6,3)(5,7)$ so far.

Comment: @Karl I cheated a bit by saying "and so on" :P

Comment: Steven Don't feel too bad, I was using Wolfram!